# Paste event on GWT

Tags: gwt, paste

I found an example of how to catch the Paste event on a TextArea on GWT but it doesn't work.

```
public MyTextArea() {
    super();
    sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
}

@Override 
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) { 
    super.onBrowserEvent(event); 
    switch (event.getTypeInt()) { 
    case Event.ONPASTE: 
        System.out.println("Paste Detected"); 
        Window.alert("Paste Works!!! Yippie!!!");
        break; 
    } 
}
```

The problem is that I never enter to onBrowserEvent ... Any suggestion ?
Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me as intended:

```
public class Starter implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(new MyTextArea());
    }

    class MyTextArea extends TextArea {
        public MyTextArea() {
            super();
            sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONPASTE:
                System.out.println("Paste Detected");
                Window.alert("Paste Works!!! Yippie!!!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On what browser are you testing it?