# How to detect copy pate event on GWT FormTextArea?

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I need to enable the "**Save**" button when user COPY - PATE something using Mouse clicks inside FormTextArea in GWT. I already tried with KeyUpHandler, ValueChangeHandler, ChangeHandler but didn't work as expected.

I already gone through
[Paste event on GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669425/paste-event-on-gwt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to catch an paste event from keyboard ctrl+v or from the contextmenu you have to override the `onBrowserEvent` Method in your widget and catch the `Event.ONPASTE`.

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
    case Event.ONPASTE:
        //do stuff
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want enable the **Save** button when your `textarea`is NOT empty.

You can use the `KeyDownHandler`

```
textArea.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
        if(textArea.getValue().isEmpty){
           //disable
        } else {
           //enable
        }
    }
});
```

Sure, you will not be notified if user paste text via `ContexMenu`but you cannot do anything for that.
You can use the `ValueChangeHandler<String>`too but it will be fired only when your `textarea`will lost the focus.

Hope it helps ...

Comment: actually there is an onpaste event fired when user uses the context menu or ctrl+c http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#ONPASTE